# Im making a web as my homework but I got stuck on dropdowns. I need a multi-layer dropdown, First one down and second one to the right

Tags: css, drop-down-menu

So as the title says I am making a web as homework but i got stuck on dropdown and I need a multi-layer dropdown, First one down and second one to the right, to make a multi dropdown menu. My html looks like this

**HTML**

```
<nav>
    <div>
        <img src="pics/logo.png" alt="logo">
        <a href="">BMW</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Vozidla
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1
                        <ul>
                            <li>subitem 1</li>
                            <li>subitem 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Item 2
                        <ul>
                            <li>subitem 1</li>
                            <li>subitem 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Elektromobily
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1
                        <ul>
                            <li>subitem 1</li>
                            <li>subitem 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Item 2
                        <ul>
                            <li>subitem 1</li>
                            <li>subitem 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Sluzby
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Kontakt
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>zavrieť menu</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Prihlásenie</button>
        <button>=</button>
    </div>
</nav>
```

and to be more accurate: I need to show the **item 1 and 2** while hovering over direct children of **.menu** this should go underneath, this part works but then i need to show the **subitem 1 and 2** while hovering over **item 1 or 2**.

I already had a css for the first hover underneath but i couldnt get the subitems to hide to then get on with making the hover. I used a bunch of selectors but you can use classes or IDs it doesnt really matter

im currently using this css

**CSS**

```
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
}
nav :nth-child(1) a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
.menu > li{
    position: relative;
}
.menu > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
    text-align: center;
    width: 150%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
li > ul {
    list-style: none;
}
.menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: initial;
    border: 2px black solid;
    background-color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
#submenu > ul {
    display: none;
}
nav div:nth-child(3) button:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
.menu li:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
.menu li:nth-child(5) button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
button {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav div:nth-child(1) {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) a {
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .menu {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 20px;
        height: 100vh;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        position: fixed;
        left: -200%;
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    nav div:nth-child(3) button:nth-child(2) {
        display: initial;
    }
    .menu li:nth-child(5) {
        display: initial;
    }
    .menu > li > ul {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .menu > li:hover > ul {
        z-index: 2;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 25px ;
    }   
}




body {background-color: black;}  /* this is here only so you can see the white text im using*/
```

if javascript helps with it you can ofc use that too

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does it you want?
I add red line at items, blue line at subitems for understanding well.

```css
nav {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    height: 100px;
    color: white;
}
nav :nth-child(1) a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
}
.menu {
    display: flex;
    list-style: none;
    justify-content: space-around;
    height: 60px;
    align-items: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
.menu ul{
    padding:0;
}
.menu li {
    list-style: none;
    padding:5px;
    margin:0;
    text-align:left;
}
.menu > li{
    position: relative;
}
.menu > li > ul {
    position: absolute;
    top: 100%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: rgb(110, 110, 110);
    text-align: center;
    width: 150%;
    display: none;
    z-index: 1;
}
.menu > li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
    border: 2px black solid;
    background-color: rgb(96, 96, 96);
    border-radius: 5px;
    z-index: -1;
    width: 100px;
    z-index: 1;
}
.menu > li > ul > li{
  border:solid 1px red;
}
.menu > li > ul > li > ul{
  display:none;
  border:solid 1px blue;
}
.menu > li > ul > li:hover > ul{
  display:block  
}
#submenu > ul {
    display: none;
}
nav div:nth-child(3) button:nth-child(2) {
    display: none;
}
.menu li:nth-child(5) {
    display: none;
}
.menu li:nth-child(5) button {
    height: 50px;
    width: 200px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
}
button {
    border-radius: 5px;
    background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
nav div:nth-child(1) {
    display: flex;
    text-align: center;
    gap: 10px;
}
nav div:nth-child(1) a {
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
    color: white;
}
@media (max-width: 650px) {
    .menu {
        flex-direction: column;
        justify-content: center;
        gap: 20px;
        height: 100vh;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 30px;
        position: fixed;
        left: -200%;
        transition: all 1s ease;
    }
    nav div:nth-child(3) button:nth-child(2) {
        display: initial;
    }
    .menu li:nth-child(5) {
        display: initial;
    }
    .menu > li > ul {
        z-index: 1;
    }
    .menu > li:hover > ul {
        z-index: 2;
        font-weight: normal;
        font-size: 25px ;
    }   
}




body {background-color: black;}  /* this is here only so you can see the white text im using*/
```

```html
<nav>
    <div>
        <img src="pics/logo.png" alt="logo">
        <a href="">BMW</a>
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul class="menu">
            <li>Vozidla
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1
                        <ul>
                            <li>subitem 1</li>
                            <li>subitem 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Item 2
                        <ul>
                            <li>subitem 1</li>
                            <li>subitem 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Elektromobily
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1
                        <ul>
                            <li>subitem 1</li>
                            <li>subitem 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li>Item 2
                        <ul>
                            <li>subitem 1</li>
                            <li>subitem 2</li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Sluzby
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>Kontakt
                <ul>
                    <li>Item 1</li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>zavrieť menu</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div>
        <button>Prihlásenie</button>
        <button>=</button>
    </div>
</nav>
```